# How to mock/override a method defined in base class in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

So I have a base class that has a following function:

```
public handleError(){
 //some code
}
```

Now I'm writing test case for my child component that inherits it and due to some chain of event it actually goes through the above method and returns an error.

How can I override/stub this method?

I tried `stub()` and `callFake` to try to hijack this method but the execution still passes though the one defined in base class:

```
it('Should call super ngOnInit()', async () => {
  const { instance } = await shallow.render();

  spyOn(instance, 'handleError').and.callFake(()=>{
    return "error"
  });
  //spyOn(service, 'myMethod').and.stub();

  const SuperNgOnInitSpy = spyOnSuper(ListBase, 'ngOnInit');
  instance.ngOnInit();

  expect(SuperNgOnInitSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: It would be great if you could create StackBlitz Here is the URL if you need boilerplate for the test: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-jasmine-ftvhck?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Actually there too many layers of code in my actual code base.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to check if the inherited method is executed or not (by using the above method), since the inherited methods are applied to the class, instead just test if the method `handleError` has been called, this will save you a lot of time! please try the below code!

```
it('Should call super ngOnInit()', async () => {
  const { instance } = await shallow.render();
  spyOn(instance, 'handleError').and.callFake(()=>{
    return "error"
  });
  instance.ngOnInit();    
  expect(instance.handleError).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: The problem here is that it still goes ahead and executes what’s written inside the parent component which results in an error since it can’t find those services.

Comment: @ABGR create a mock for all the methods on the parent so that nothing gets executed and the test case passes!

Comment: The problem is in this method only if I comment that out or override in child method the test cases passes. So I want to ‘override’ handleError in unit tests.